# Looping through visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have to filter data and then delete some specific rows based upon a condition.

When I use For Each loop and delete a row inside the loop and the rows move up so as to avoid blank row.

However, this makes the row immediate below the deleted row unavailable as it had shifted up and already counted.

e.g. I have a set of **visible data** (a1,b2,c3,d4,e5).

When I loop using

```
For Each rCell In ws.Range(DataRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

and say rCell has value b2 and I delete this row. Now, c3 moves to the second position and on moving to the next cycle in the loop it moves directly to d4(current third position) and skips c3.
I cannot find any useful alternative looping also. Please help.

My current piece of code: Logic works but skips rows on deletion. I cannot share the data.

```
For Each currrentRow In ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    row_marker = currrentRow.Row
    For i = LBound(bankArray, 1) To UBound(bankArray, 1)
        If LCase(bankArray(i, 1)) = LCase(currrentRow.Value) Or LCase(bankArray(i, 3)) = LCase(currrentRow.Value) Then
            If bankArray(i, 1) <> bankArray(i, 2) Then
                
                date_marker = Cells(row_marker, 1).Value
                cycle_marker = Cells(row_marker, 2).Value
                amount = Cells(row_marker, 8).Value
                RowCount = 0
                
                ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
                        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, CDate(date_marker))
                ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cycle_marker
                ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=bankArray(i, 2)
                
                On Error Resume Next
                    RowCount = ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
                        
                    If RowCount = 0 Then
                        currrentRow.Value = bankArray(i, 2)
                    Else:
                        Set parent_row = ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1)
                        parent_amount = Cells(parent_row.Row, 8).Value
                        Cells(parent_row.Row, 8).Value = parent_amount + amount
                        Set currrentRow = currrentRow.Offset(-1, 0)
                        ws.Rows(row_marker).Delete
                    End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                
                If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="DR"
                ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="PUBLIC"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next currrentRow
```

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count`
 issue, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400102/filtered-row-count/62401178#62401178)

Comment: What is the relationship between `ws` and `Activesheet` ?  Same sheet, or different?  Anyway, the best way to handle this is to build up a range consisting of the rows to be deleted (using Application.Union) and delete that range when done processing all of the cells.  See Nadine's answer here for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722122/vba-excel-delete-rows-with-specific-valuehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722122/vba-excel-delete-rows-with-specific-value

Comment: My issue actually comes in the Else: code part where I delete a row. Loop simply skips next row as it moved up. Thanks for pointing out by row count issue is secondary. @Dy.Lee

Comment: @TimWilliams :  ws and Activesheet are same.Link leads to page not found!

Comment: Link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722122/vba-excel-delete-rows-with-specific-value

Answer (score 0):

Solved it @Nadine's way as suggested by @TimWilliams. Created a range of rows to be deleted and deleted all at once after exiting loop.
If someone has a better solution please suggest.

Edited Code:

```
For Each currrentRow In ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
row_marker = currrentRow.Row
For i = LBound(bankArray, 1) To UBound(bankArray, 1)
    If LCase(bankArray(i, 1)) = LCase(currrentRow.Value) Or LCase(bankArray(i, 3)) = LCase(currrentRow.Value) Then
        If bankArray(i, 1) <> bankArray(i, 2) Then
            
            date_marker = Cells(row_marker, 1).Value
            cycle_marker = Cells(row_marker, 2).Value
            amount = Cells(row_marker, 8).Value
            filterRowCount = 0
            
            ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
                    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, CDate(date_marker))
            ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cycle_marker
            ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=bankArray(i, 2)
            
            On Error Resume Next
                filterRowCount = ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
                    
                If filterRowCount = 0 Then
                    currrentRow.Value = bankArray(i, 2)
                Else:
                    Set parent_row = ActiveSheet.Range(DataRange).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1)
                    parent_amount = Cells(parent_row.Row, 8).Value
                    Cells(parent_row.Row, 8).Value = parent_amount + amount

                    If Not IsNumeric(LBound(rowsToDelete)) Then
                        ReDim rowsToDelete(0 To 0)
                        rowsToDelete(0) = row_marker
                    Else
                        ReDim Preserve rowsToDelete(LBound(rowsToDelete) To UBound(rowsToDelete) + 1)
                        rowsToDelete(UBound(rowsToDelete)) = row_marker
                    End If
                    selectedRowCount = UBound(rowsToDelete) - LBound(rowsToDelete) + 1
                End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="DR"
            ActiveSheet.Range(workRange).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="PUBLIC"
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next i
Next currrentRow

For x = LBound(rowsToDelete) To UBound(rowsToDelete)
If rangeToDelete Is Nothing Then
    Set rangeToDelete = ActiveSheet.Rows(rowsToDelete(x))
Else
    Set rangeToDelete = Union(rangeToDelete, ActiveSheet.Rows(rowsToDelete(x)))
End If
Next x

If Not rangeToDelete Is Nothing Then rangeToDelete.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```